# Is P vs NP, a paradox in a hypothetical perspective?

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, philosophy, hypercomputation

In a hypothetical scenario, where a precise and formal definition does not exist here, and thus expressed with analogies and verbal reasoning for the sake of simplifying the P, NP problem.

A(lan) Turing Machine arrives to the "Universal-Algorithm-Island", and meets Christopher, an oracle with a True or False response.

ATM: "Long time no seen".

Christopher: "True".

---

**Case 1**

ATM: "... do all machines in 'UAI' have NP algorithm to solve them?".

Christopher: "True".

ATM: "Do all machines in 'UAI' have no NP algorithm to solve them?".

Christopher: "False".

**Case 2**

ATM: "... do all machines in 'UAI' have P algorithm to solve them?".

Christopher: "False".

ATM: "Do all machines in 'UAI' have no P algorithm to solve them?".

Christopher: "True".

---

Otherwise, the oracle is lying.

Generally speaking, in regard to the above - both classes cannot be equal, otherwise its a contradiction.

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 4):

This makes no sense to me.  You imagine a scenario that is self-contradictory, and then observe that it is a contradiction, and.. then what?  All that proves is that your scenario can't happen.

It's like me imagining scenario where I walk up to a knight who never lies, and then the knight tells me "2+2=5".  Well, that scenario is self-contradictory, so it can't happen -- it is not internally consistent.  I don't get to conclude that P!=NP from this scenario, or that the Goldbach conjecture is true, or anything useful at all.  All I can conclude is that my scenario can't actually happen.

The complexity P, NP are mathematical objects with a precise, formal definition.  The notion of "in a hypothetical perspective" has no meaning here.  Either P = NP, or it doesn't.  It's not the kind of statement where there are multiple valid perspectives on it.  It would be like me trying to claim that "2*3 = 7 from a hypothetical perspective" - nonsense.  This is not something you can reason about with analogies or verbal reasoning.

I don't think you are going down a fruitful path.  The way you are approaching this doesn't seem to engage with the actual P vs NP question at all.

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your response. Unfortunately to claim the idea of going down a wrong fruitful path would be a wrong say - either tell me you have a fruitful path to solving one of the greatest problems.

Answer (score -4):

Interesting perspectives presented by (Lance Fortnow, The Golden Ticket: P, NP, and the Search for the Impossible, 2013, Chapter 7), has shown analogies to the Liar-paradox, Circuits and more, relating to the P, NP problem.

This tackles directly the hypothetical perspective, in sense of being a paradox, which brings up intuition of why P, NP problem is also one.

---

An interesting solution given by 'ChatGPT Dec 15 Version', is the following:
"...
The P versus NP problem is similar to the liar paradox in that it involves a self-referential aspect, in this case the relationship between the time it takes a computer to solve a problem and the time it takes a computer to verify a solution. Just as with the liar paradox, it is not clear whether it is possible to definitively resolve the P versus NP problem, and it continues to be an active area of research in computer science.
"

Comment: ChatGPT does not give solutions any more than Google does. ChatGPT regurgitates and recombines text provided by humans. Determining whether that text provides a valid solution to the question being asked is beyond CharGPT's capabilities.